# Trying to get image from firebase so that user can set profile image but its blank

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

Im trying to allow users to click on the image item and choose a picture from their galley. this picture should then be pushed to firebase and added to the image view automatically but it is showing up blank after I close the application. I have tried numerous methods but cant seem to get it working. here is where i implement everything:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ImageView imageView;
    public static final int IMAGE_CODE = 1;
    Uri imageUri;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseUser user;
    String userid;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userid = user.getUid();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Images");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads").child(userid);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openimage();
            }
        });
        profileImage(); 
   }

   private void profileImage(){
   databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                  Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(upload.getUplaodUri()).into(imageView);
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
      });
   }

   private void openimage() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGE_CODE);
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                // You don't have permission
                checkPermission1();
            } else {
                // Do as per your logic
            }

        }
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data && data.getData() != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(imageView);

            fileUploader();

        }
    }
    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));
    }
    private void fileUploader(){
        if(imageUri != null){
            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(userid + ".jpeg");

            reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            Upload upload = new Upload(uri.toString());
                            databaseReference.setValue(upload).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                profileImage();
            }
        });
                        }
                    });



                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
;;
                }
            });

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
}
```

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjq6S.png)

Edit:

```
2020-05-03 15:55:51.232 25230-25407/com.example.carcrashdetection E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2020-05-03 15:55:51.235 25230-25407/com.example.carcrashdetection E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:76)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Also the image is in a navigation drawer and should be unique to each user. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I doesn't work : taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString()

Comment: what should i use instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
   @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
           Upload upload = new Upload(uri.toString());
           String uploadId = databaseReference.child(userid).push().getKey();
           databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
    }
});
```

Firebase Storage [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)

And there is a problem in this line:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(upload).into(imageView);
```

upload is an object. You should use upload.getUploadUri()

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
   for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Upload upload = ds.getValue(Upload.class);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(upload.getUplaodUri()).into(imageView);    
   }

}
```

You always see last uploaded image this way. If a user has an image you don't need to use uploadId.

Profile image:

```
    Upload upload = new Upload(uri.toString());
    databaseReference.setValue(upload);
```

and:

```
 if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
       Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
       Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(upload.getUplaodUri()).into(imageView); 
 }
```

more useful for you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213052/discussion-on-answer-by-kasim-ozdemir-trying-to-get-image-from-firebase-so-that).